# Python Tkinter Clear frame and associate user's answer to a value

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I am trying to clear the frame between each question that is asked in the multiple choice survey but I would like the frame itself to stay. I tried to created a next button that will allow the user to skip to the next question but the frame doesn't appear when I run my code (No error message is appering either).

And in order to store the answers of the user to the questions, is it better to use the values (1,2,3,4,5) of the radiobuttons or the variables of the radiobuttons.

Here is my code:

```
from Tkinter import *

fenetre = Tk()
fenetre.title("Life Quiz")
from random import shuffle

#questions 

quest_1 = "What is your favorite color?"
quest_2 = "Which of these animals do you like the most?"
quest_3 = "Which of these superpowers would you want to have the most?"
quest_4 = "Which food would you want to eat right now?"
quest_5 = "If you could only bring one thing on an island, what would it be?"

#liste de réponse

list_reponse = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"]

#Associé liste_reponse avec IntVar()

list_reponse[0] = IntVar()
list_reponse[1] = IntVar()
list_reponse[2] = IntVar()
list_reponse[3] = IntVar()
list_reponse[4] = IntVar()




class Questions(object):

#fonction pour afficher les questions et les choix de réponses

    def __init__(self, master, n_question):
        self.master = master
        self.liste_choix =[ [quest_1, "Blue", "White", "Yellow", "RAINBOWS", "Red"], [ quest_2, "Blue Whale", "Pig", "Cat", "Unicorns", "Dog"], [quest_3, "Make it rain whenever you want", "Transform yourself into a ladder", "Invisibility when no one's around", "Read the mind of unicorns", "Ability to fly" ], [quest_4, "Ice cream", "Sushi", "Salad", "Cupcakes", "Pizza"] ,[quest_5, "Nothing...", "A fishing rod", "A book", "A leprechaun", "A knife"] ]

        self.liste_choix_questions = self.liste_choix [n_question]
        shuffle(self.liste_choix_questions)
        self.display_frame = None
        self.next_question = 0

        def display_next(self):
            if self.next_question < len(self.liste_choix_questions):
                if self.display_frame:
                    self.display_frame.destroy()
                self.display_frame=Frame(self.master)
                self.display_frame.grid(row=0, column=0)
                Label(self.display_frame,
                      text=self.liste_choix_questions[0],
                      bg="lightblue").grid(row=0, column=0)


        display_next(self)

        R1 = Radiobutton(fenetre, text= self.liste_choix[n_question][1], variable= list_reponse[n_question], value=1) 
        R1.pack( anchor = W )
        R2 = Radiobutton(fenetre, text= self.liste_choix[n_question][2], variable= list_reponse[n_question], value=2)
        R2.pack( anchor = W )
        R3 = Radiobutton(fenetre, text= self.liste_choix[n_question][3], variable= list_reponse[n_question], value=3)
        R3.pack( anchor = W)
        R4 = Radiobutton(fenetre, text= self.liste_choix[n_question][4], variable= list_reponse[n_question], value=4)
        R4.pack( anchor = W )
        R5 = Radiobutton(fenetre, text= self.liste_choix[n_question][5], variable= list_reponse[n_question], value=5)
        R5.pack( anchor = W )

        Button(self.display_frame, text="next",
               command=display_next).grid(row=1, column=0)
        n_question += 1




Q = Questions(fenetre,1)
fenetre.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use an inner frame to hold your radiobuttons. Then, you can delete the frame which will delete all of the radiobuttons. Finally, you can recreate the frame with new radiobuttons.

Another solution is to simply iterate over the radiobuttons, reconfiguring them for the current question (assuming all questions have the same number of choices).